# JavaScript Confirm Box not working when click confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to make a confirm box to inform user if they really want to show password field in table. But it not working when click Confirm.

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<span onclick="myFunction()" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye fa-eye-slash field-icon toggle-password"></span>
<span style="display:none;" id="password-field">123456</span>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
          
          if (confirm("Are you sure you want to show your password on the screen?)) {
              
              $(".toggle-password-<?=$model->id?>").click(function() {

            $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye-slash");
             
            });
                

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".toggle-password-<?=$model->id?>").click(function(){
                $("#password-field-<?=$model->id?>").toggle();
                });
            }); 
        
          } else {
            //do nothing
          }
          
        }
```

Please help me with this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's an example for fixed code:
https://codepen.io/mitni455/pen/YzwJwNL?editors=1010

I have removed the PHP specific stuff.

```js
function myFunction() {
          
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to show your password on the screen?")) {

      $('#password-field').show();
      

  } else {
      $('#password-field').hide();
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">
  My Function
</button>
<span style="display:none;" id="password-field">
    123456
</span>
```

OK a few things here:

- When you click confirm you are simply adding 2 more click handlers and a document onload handler (it's also a memory leak).
- The code `$(".toggle-password-<?=$model->id?>").click` adds another (redundant) click handler to the `.toggle-password-123` button
- You never made any call to show/hide or change the display value for the `span#password-field`... this is resolved in the refactored code above
- You missed the closing quotation in the `confirm("Are you sure you want to show your password on the screen?")`
- `$(document).ready` won't fire and is redundant because the document will have already loaded by the time you click the button. So you can remove that.

Here's what you did: on confirm:

1. add a click handler to `.toggle-password-{id}` (which is the
   button you just clicked);
2. add a document onload event handler (to a document already loaded);
3. once the document has loaded (will never fire), add another click handler to `.toggle-password-{id};`
4. Finally, when that is clicked THEN toggle the password field

Comment: Thank you so much for helping and for the knowledge!!!

Comment: My pleasure! Glad it helps ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye fa-eye-slash field-icon toggle-password">Click me</button>
<span style="display:none;" id="password-field">123456</span>

<script type="text/javascript">

function toggledisplay(elementID)
     {
        (function(style) {
             style.display = style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
                })(document.getElementById(elementID).style);
     }

function myFunction() {  
        
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to show your password on the screen?")) {
        toggledisplay("password-field");
        
      }
}
```

I used the `button` tag to be able to see where to click, when replicating your code.
Then, added the function `toggledisplay(elementID)` to toggle the display style whenever the `confirm` is `True`.